# Установка kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Создаю загрузочную флешку с kali linux, пробовал и unetbootin и с rufus. При загрузке с неё нет кнопки install. Есть Start installer, думаю, попробую на неё. Вроде всё идёт хорошо, но потом он мне выдаёт, что не удаётся считать данные с CD-ROM (загружаюсь с флешки, CD ROM'а вообще нет). При этом, когда тот же iso кидаю в VirtualBox, кнопка install есть и установка прошла успешно.

Comment: попробуйте руфус от администратора запустить)

Comment: Если пишете из под венды - Руфус, если из под линукса - dd.

Comment: Вопрос внимательно прочитайте, он закатывает, он при установке с флешки не работает, так как дистрибутив настроен на режим чтения при установке. Разницы нет, пробовал и то и то при закатке. Разве что можно образ с виртуалки на реальную систему развернуть или на диск закатать образ. Можно так же в дистрибутив влезть и отключить защиту, но это непроваславненько целосность нарушать.

Answer (score 0):

Устанока Kali возможна лишь с диска на реальную машину(там есть система проверки по хешу и по носителю). В виртуальной машины есть маркеры VT-x. Сделано это для целосности системы, так как цель системы все таки проверка сети и надежности компонентов. Ну так же есть всякие утилиты для клонирования жестких дисков, чтоже вариант.Советую вам USB привод, если нет иного. Тоже самое с BlackArch Linux. Есть более дорогой вариант, флешка с физическим переключением режимов чтения-записи, но привод дешевле.В rufus при записи выбери DD образ или попробуй вынуть флешку и вставить возможно поможет, но мне не помогло.

Comment: А если установить его аналог - например, Parrot security OS, можно будет его установить с флешки?

Comment: Parrot по моему идет, но я поясняю, сделано в Kali это для того, чтобы вы зашифровали и установили систему. Нужно это только для доступа к железу. Сходи на cybrary.it сначала, чтобы ред хатом не стать. Ну или вот https://pluralsight.com. Зацени курсы Лео, начальные нудные. А паррот попробуй, в принципе отличия несерьезные. С прокси там проще.

Comment: Установил Parrot, доволен. А cybrary не робит, 406 ошибку выдаёт, помню, месяц назад тоже самое было. А на pluralsight платно, школьник, как я, не потянет)))

Comment: В общем пиши в личку,скину красную таблетку https://twitter.com/vdvwolf